# Unable to correct problems you held broken packages (nala)

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, nala

I am trying to install nala, but I get this error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nala : Depends: python3-anyio but it is not installable
        Depends: python3-httpx but it is not installable
        Depends: python3-rich but it is not installable
        Depends: python3-tomli but it is not installable
        Depends: python3-typer but it is not installable
        Recommends: python3-socksio but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried using `-f`, I did `apt update`, and I tried installing the dependencies manually, but neither have worked.

Here is the link for the [nala installation instructions](https://gitlab.com/volian/nala/-/wikis/Installation), and I'm installing using the repo and key.

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: The repo and key don't work because the pre-built binary package seems incompatible with 20.04. That's why you get the dependency errors and the `held broken packages` error. You can try the package with 22.04, or you can follow the build instructions for 20.04.

Comment: try this, I also had a problem with nala on Ubuntu 20.04, it works for me according to this procedure.[How to use the Nala package manager on Ubuntu](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/how-to-use-the-nala-package-manager-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Edit**: Since this answer was written, the `nala-legacy` package has been removed, since it was too difficult to maintain. Nala is officially now only supported on Ubuntu 22.04 and newer.*

### Old Answer

As per the [Nala wiki page](https://gitlab.com/volian/nala/-/wikis/Installation), older releases (Debian Stable and Ubuntu 20.04) should use the `nala-legacy` package, which is built for older dependencies.

Since you already installed the "wrong" `nala` package, first remove it using:

```
sudo apt remove nala
```

Then install the correct `nala` package using:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install nala-legacy
```

The latest `nala` package can only be used on Ubuntu 22.04 or later.

Comment: The voilan repo still maintains the `nala-legacy` package for 20.04.

Comment: @RaelGugelminCunha use this command istead: sudo apt remove nala --remove-essential

Comment: @RaelGugelminCunha Not anymore, that's been pulled too. :/

Comment: @Seth I moved the edit about removed package to the top. Thanks!